# Would it make sense to use group norm with transformers?

Tags: machine-learning, normalization, transformers

Transformers commonly use layer normalization, as explained here: [Why do transformers use layer norm instead of batch norm?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/474440/why-do-transformers-use-layer-norm-instead-of-batch-norm).

One of the arguments in that post is that batch normalization is not used in Transformers because sentence length might vary in a given batch.

However, group normalization also works on a single input (doesn't require a batch).
Would it be possible to use group normalization instead of layer normalization in a Transformer?

Comment: Original paper on group norm: https://eccv2018.org/openaccess/content_ECCV_2018/papers/Yuxin_Wu_Group_Normalization_ECCV_2018_paper.pdf 
A useful looking article comparing batch/layer/instance/group norms: https://towardsdatascience.com/what-is-group-normalization-45fe27307be7   (not specifically about transformers, though, so not sure if it answers your question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transformer data is `B x N x D`, where B is batch size, N is the max sentence length in the batch, and D is the dimension. There is no equivalent of the channel you get in image data (`B x C x W x H`).

[GroupNorm](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.GroupNorm.html) splits the channel dimension into groups, and finds the means and variance of each group. That pytorch doc page says:

> `num_channels` must be divisible by `num_groups`

As `num_channels` is effectively 1 for a transformer, 1 is also the only possible value for `num_groups`, making it pointless.

**Additional:** Even if you could, is there any reason to prefer it over LayerNorm? Answers on the link in the question mention that LayerNorm works well over a distributed model (https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/511253/5503) and another references https://arxiv.org/abs/2201.03545 saying that LayerNorm works just as well as BatchNorm in ConvNet.

Comment: Wasn't `D` the channel?

Comment: Yes, D can be considered as the equivalent of C.
One could split D into group and compute the statistics for each group separately.